# sencha 2.4 [ERR] Unknown command: "package"

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've installed all Required Software for sencha followed by [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4.0/#!/guide/getting_started) on my Ubuntu 14.04

- Download and unzip Sencha Touch 2.4
- Sencha Cmd 5.0
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
- Android SDK L

then I generate an application with:

```
$ mkdir MyApp
$ cd MyApp
$ sencha -sdk /path/to/touch generate app MyApp .
```

follow [sencha first app docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4.0/#!/guide/first_app) and change content of MyApp, After that build it using this command: `$sencha app build`, then create android simulator packager json called `androidsim.json`.

```
    {
    "applicationName":"MyApp",
    "applicationId":"com.test.myapp.app",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "versionCode":"1",
    "icon": {
        "36":"resources/icons/Icon_Android36.png",
        "48":"resources/icons/Icon_Android48.png",
        "57":"resources/icons/Icon.png"
    },
    "inputPath":"/path/to/MyApp/",
    "outputPath":"/path/to/MyApp/build/",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"AndroidSimulator",
    "notificationConfiguration":"debug",
    "sdkPath":"/path/to/android-sdks", //mention the SDK path on your system
    "androidAPILevel":"20",
    "permissions":[
        "INTERNET",
        "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "CAMERA",
        "VIBRATE",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "CALL_PHONE",
        "RECORD_AUDIO",
        "RECORD_VIDEO",
        "READ_CONTACTS",
        "WRITE_CONTACTS",
        "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    ],
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",

        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

but after I run `sencha app package run androidsim.json` i got error `[ERR] Unknown command: "package"` following [sencha building doc](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4.0/#!/guide/building).

thanks for help :/

Comment: try isolating the problem, without the simulator do you get any errors?